# don't work tag fmt:setBundle

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, locale

Friends who will prompt the decision. I have the educational project. 
The language locale for the jsp-page doesn't work. I use the standard tags:  and . I Made everything as according to the studenttbook.
Page jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-  8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" scope="session" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="resources.pagecontent" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><fmt:message key="tr_titlepage"/></title>
</head>
<body>
<c:import url="${uriJspHeader}" charEncoding="utf-8"/>
<br>
<h1><fmt:message key="tr_pagename"/></h1>....
```

I established jar-files in folders. 'ROOT/web/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1. web/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1'
files: pagecontent_ru_RU.properties, pagecontent_en_US.properties..... are in the folder:'ROOT/web/jsp/resources'

Keys are written down truly, the pagecontent files... are filled according to keys - I rechecked many times. But result: '??? (key)???' it appears in those places where there has to be a text from files. I.e. the handler doesn't "see" the boundled resources. But other tags, such as 'fmt:formatnumber' work normally.

Who knows, what I made not correctly???

Answer (score 0):

Everything is very simple. Folder /resources with files of resources need to be placed in folder /src, (proceeding from basename = "resources.pagecontent") then everything will OK. :))